# How to make jQuery parse my error response represented as a valid json?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here is my code:

```
      $.ajax({
        url: "/api/invoice/" + newInvoice._id,
        type: 'PUT',
        data: JSON.stringify(newInvoice),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
      })
        .success(function () {
          $('#statusLine').text('Successfully submitted invoice {0}. Click here to dismiss.'.format(newInvoice._id));
        })
        .error(function (err) {
          alert(err);
        });
```

The request:

```
PUT http://localhost:8000/api/invoice/16211 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 770
Origin: http://localhost:8000
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Referer: http://localhost:8000/invoice.html?id=16211
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

{"items":[{"id":...
```

The request body is actually a valid json, I have just truncated it for brevity.

The response:

```
HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1386
ETag: 250542419
Connection: keep-alive

{
  "msg": "Cannot update the invoice #16211, because it has already been updated by someone else.",
  "invoice": {
    "items": [
      {...
```

Again, the response is a completely valid json, truncated for brevity.

As expected, the `error` handler is invoked with the `err` object. However, how can I get hold on the parsed json? Of course, I could check that the content-type of the response is json and then parse the `err.responseText` myself, but isn't it what jQuery ajax is supposed to do for me? I mean, it does so for my `$.get` queries when I get the objects from the server.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

This is a correction to https://stackoverflow.com/a/12310751/80002:

Doing the request:

```
var ajax = $.ajax(...
```

Processing the error response:

```
var res, ct = ajax.getResponseHeader("content-type") || '';
if (ct.indexOf('json') > -1) {
  res = $.parseJSON(err.responseText);
  // process the response here
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For an error message with a non-200<sup>1</sup> [HTTP status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), the content will not be parsed by jQuery. If you'd really like not to parse the returned result to JSON yourself, you would have to return a HTTP status 200 and use the `success` (`done`) callbacks.

It's a good sign that you're using (from your example) HTTP code 409, and I think you should keep doing that - just bite the bullet and parse the JSON manually in your error handler. If the parsing fails, something else has gone wrong (like a temporary network failure), but this will allow you to build a nice API that you (and possibly others) can consume without having to build too much error checking into the success function.

*Keep `success` for the happy results, and `error` for unhappy results.*

<sup>1</sup> Technically any 2xx status should be considered successful; [in jQuery `(status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 304)` counts as something successful](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/05337e78fa68aac3a3d703d7cc59f145f13ea779/src/ajax.js#L477).

Answer (score 46):

I ran into the same issue and found a slightly different way from @Barmar's answer.

Aswell as `responseText`, there is also a `responseJSON` property, so you could do the following:

```
var json_response = err.responseJSON.msg;
```

If you `console.log(err);` there's a few properties in there that you might wish to use in your error message on the page.

Comment: That is such a useful property! :)

Comment: this is so clever :)

Comment: i think the problem is that the response doesn't always get parsed into `responseJSON` for an unsuccessful response.  it did for chrome on mac but did not for chrome on windows nor safari on iOS.

Comment: `err` is this case is the jqXHR object and `responseJSON` may be undefined if the response text could not be parsed, so `json_response = err.responseJSON ? err.responseJSON.msg : "some error happened";` may be better.

Answer (score 12):

Call `$.parseJSON` explicitly in your error callback:

```
(...)
.error(function (err) {
  var msg = $.parseJSON(err).msg;
  alert(msg);
});
```

Comment: +1 I wish I could mark both yours and Joel's replies as one answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple to get a JSON format. It's already featured by jQuery.

```
var error = error.responseJSON
```